# PowerBI - Join DirectQuery and Imported tables in DAX

Tags: join, powerbi, powerquery

I have a DirectQuery table (Weather) which is sourced from an Azure SQL server. I would like to join this with an Imported table (Buckles) from an Excel sheet sourced from SharePoint Online.

Both tables have a UID field that is made up of a concatenation between a SiteID and timestamp. The UID field is named differently for each table.

I have created a One-To-Many relationship between the two tables.

I have tried to create a new DAX table using a NATURALINNERJOIN on Weather and Buckles but I get this error:

"No common join columns detected. The join function 'NATURALINNERJOIN' requires at-least one common join column."

I am confident it is not a problem with the underlying data because I've created a new imported Excel table (Test) with a selection of the data from Weather and I'm able to successfully create the join on Test and Buckles.

Is the joining of DirectQuery and Imported tables supported? I feel like this may be a type casting issue, but as far as I can see, both UID fields are set as Text.

Answer (score 0):

> The UID field is named differently for each table.

I suspect this may be the issue. `NATURALINNERJOIN` looks for matching column names
 and [if the two tables have no common column names, an error is returned.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/naturalinnerjoin-function-dax)

---

Note that if you create a calculated DAX table using a DirectQuery source, I don't think that table will still act like DirectQuery. If I understand correctly, it will materialize the calculated table into your model and DAX that references that calculated table no longer points back to the SQL server (and consequently will only update when the calculated table gets rebuilt).

Comment: Yes I thought that too, but many people elsewhere have said the documentation is wrong and if you have a relationship created between the two tables you must use unique column names! In any case, I've tried giving them matching names and the error is still there

Comment: Weird. I guess you could do the join a bit more manually, specifying exactly how to build it rather than trying to get it to figure it out automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This function is not supported for use in DirectQuery mode when used in calculated columns. Your column being joined on is a calculated column.